# Suggestions for Data Access Interface Name

Tags: language-agnostic

I am looking for suggestions for an interface name.

The interface is for the primitive CRUD methods that will be defined later in the DAL, however I need to use it in a lower-level API. The interface itself will just have the four members, Create(), Read(), Update(), and Delete().

I am currently thinking something along the lines of IDataAccessPrimatives, but am very ambivalant on that name.  What do you gals/guys suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go with IDataAccessOperation/IDataAccessService.

This clearly shows the responsibility of the interface.

Another options is to replace Service with Manager in the later option.

Answer (score 4):

How about ICantBelieveItsNotButter ?

Or, ICanReadUpsideDown?

Or, (more seriously), **IPersistData**

Answer (score 2):

Drop "Primitives."

I'd go with **IDataAccess** unless you need to differentiate from another "primitive" DAL interface.

Use the most straightforward names possible for your commonly used interfaces.

Comment: The only problem that I have with that is that I feel that as we move forward and actually start designing the DAL that this interface will be part of a larger interface for data access.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) pattern. How about ITableDataGateway or IGateway or some other derivative?

Answer (score 0):

**ICrud.**  Seriously.  Why not?  Every developer out to know what CRUD means.